# Python type hints in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, type-hinting, pep8

What's the proper type hints in PEP8 to type hint variable defined within the for loop or in nested for loop.

```
a: int
for a in iterable_A:
    for b in iterable_B:
        pass
```

what would be the proper PEP8 standard type hints use for **b**?
I've tried both seem to be working.

```
a: int
for a in iterable_A:
    b: int
    for b in iterable_B:
        pass
```

OR
in nested for loop.

```
a: int
b: int
for a in iterable_A:
    for b in iterable_B:
        pass
```

Comment: Either way is fine.

Comment: this will just come down to preference really, https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#where-annotations-aren-t-allowed, it just says that they can be annotated ahead of time of the loop, where you choose to do that will just be down to your preference

Comment: I wouldn't do either, and would instead make sure that `iterable_A` and `iterable_B` have useful generic types.